# custom pom.xml filename in maven multimodule

Tags: java, maven-2, maven-3

I have a maven3 multimodule project, and for a strange reason i need to customize POM filename for one of my child module (ie: module-pom.xml)

Is it possible to configure this in the parent pom ?

The strange reason is a bit long to explain sorry, but you will have the plain context.

**Context**

- I'm working on a closed source project that also use LGPLed projects. this project is called `main`
- I want `main` to declare modules of every projects, closed and opened. The full build should be made with a unique `mvn clean package` command.
- Inside the `main` reactor project, i have `lgpl-reactor` multimodule project containing 3 LGPL modules (API, Plugins and Distribution project). Some developper will have access to `lgpl-reactor` only, so i also want this project to build from its folder with `mvn clean package` command, like a fully standalone project.
- I also have `main-dist` project that is a maven-assembly-plugin only project (to build the distribution).

**The problem**

- If I add parent reference to `lgpl-reactor` pom.xml, the global `main` build works perfectly, and assembly created by `main-dist` is valid, but the standalone build of lgpl-reactor fails (main pom.xml not found).
- If I remove parent reference from `lgpl-reactor` pom.xml, the standalone `lgpl-reactor` build works, but assembly created by `main-dist` is NOT valid (missing.

**How to solve this ?**

- use another POM file *module-pom.xml* for `lgpl-reactor` module declaration inside `main` modules declaration list. When perfoming the full build from `main` project, `module-pom.xml` contains reference to parent POM and is working properly.
- use the default POM file *pom.xml* for standalon build of `lgpl-reactor`. This POM can hardly reference the parent pom with the `relativePath` property of `<parent>` tag

***But HOW can i do that ? if possible ? Or is there any better solution ?***

**Directory of the Main Reactor Project**

```
lgpl-lib [LGPL Library]
lgpl-ext [LGPL Reactor Project]
closed-core [Closed source module]
closed-spring [Closed source module]
closed-web [Closed source module]
closed-webserver [Closed source module]
main-dist [Main assembly module]
pom.xml [Main Reactor POM]
```

**Directory of the LGPL Reactor Project**

```
lgpl-api [LGPL API module]
lgpl-plugins [LGPL Plugins module]
lgpl-ext-dist [LGPL assembly module]
main-pom.xml [Main Reactor POM, copy of main pom.xml]
pom.xml [Standalone LGPL Reactor POM]
module-pom.xml [Module LGPL Reactor POM]
```

**Main Reactor POM** (pom.xml & lgpl-reactor/main-pom.xml)

```
    ...
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>main.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>main</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Main</name>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    ...
    <modules>
        <module>closed-core</module>
        <module>closed-web</module>
        <module>closed-webserver</module>
        <module>closed-spring</module>
        <module>lgpl-reactor</module>
        <module>lgpl-lib</module>
        <module>main-dist</module>
    </modules>
    ...
```

**lgpl-reactor/pom.xml**

```
...
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<artifactId>lgpl-reactor</artifactId>
<name>LGPL Reactor</name>
<packaging>pom</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>main.group</groupId>
    <artifactId>main</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <relativePath>main-pom.xml</relativePath>
</parent>
...
    ...
<modules>
    <module>lgpl-api</module>
    <module>lgpl-plugins</module>
    <module>lgpl-ext-dist</module>
</modules>
    ...
```

pom.xml of `main-dist`

```
<project>
    <parent>
        <groupId>main.group</groupId>
        <artifactId>main</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>main-dist</artifactId>

    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <description>Main Distribution</description>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>plugins-assembly</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <descriptors>
                                <descriptor>assembly.xml</descriptor>
                            </descriptors>
                            <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>closed</groupId>
            <artifactId>closed-webserver</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>closed</groupId>
            <artifactId>closed-api</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

assembly.xml of `main-dist`

```
<assembly
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
    <id>plugins-assembly</id>
    <formats>
        <format>dir</format>
        <format>zip</format>
    </formats>
    <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>

    <fileSets>
        <fileSet>
            <directory>../closed-webserver/conf</directory>
            <outputDirectory>conf</outputDirectory>
        </fileSet>
    </fileSets>

    <dependencySets>
        <dependencySet>
            <excludes><exclude>main.group:closed-webserver</exclude></excludes>
            <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
        </dependencySet>
    </dependencySets>

    <moduleSets>
        <moduleSet>
            <useAllReactorProjects>true</useAllReactorProjects>

            <includes>
                <include>main.group:closed-webserver</include>
            </includes>

            <binaries>
                <outputFileNameMapping>${module.artifactId}${dashClassifier?}.${module.extension}</outputFileNameMapping>
                <unpack>false</unpack>
                <includeDependencies>false</includeDependencies>
            </binaries>
        </moduleSet>

        <moduleSet>
            <useAllReactorProjects>true</useAllReactorProjects>

            <includes>
                <include>main.group:closed-spring</include>
            </includes>

            <binaries>
                <outputFileNameMapping>${module.artifactId}${dashClassifier?}.${module.extension}</outputFileNameMapping>
                <unpack>false</unpack>
                <includeDependencies>false</includeDependencies>
            </binaries>

        </moduleSet>

        <moduleSet>
            <useAllReactorProjects>true</useAllReactorProjects>

            <includes>
                <include>main.group:lgpl-ext-dist</include>
            </includes>

            <binaries>
                <outputDirectory>plugins</outputDirectory>
                <unpack>false</unpack>
                <includeDependencies>true</includeDependencies>
            </binaries>

        </moduleSet>
    </moduleSets>

</assembly>
```

Comment: Can't you tell us what that *strange reason* is? That would probably help us to understand why you need this and then maybe come up with a solution.

Comment: Ok, i have added some details ...

Comment: What about the custom pom route did not work for you? In the multi-module manifest, you can specify the custom POM file name of the child artifact.

Comment: This is answered here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/33494665/318054

Answer (score 11):

You can override default pom.xml. Maven have -f command option.

```
mvn -f <path>/pom.xml clean install
```

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to change the folder structure into the following.

```
root (pom.xml)
  +-- closed-core
  +-- closed-web
  +-- closed-webserver
  +-- closed-spring
  +-- lgpl-reactor
         +-- lgpl-lib
         +-- lgpl-dist
         +-- lgpl-etc..
```

Than you don't need a separte module-pom.xml file. You can work with pom.xml as default.

If you wan't to build lgpl-reactory you can simply give:

```
mvn -pl lgpl-reactory clean package
```

if you have dependencies within the other modules to lgpl you can use:

```
mvn -am -pl lgpl-reactory clean package
```

This will build also all dependent modules.

Comment: Problem is that the root pom.xml won't be published as LGPL and won't be available on the github repository of lgpl-reactor ... So, user cloning the lgpl-reactor from GitHub can't do that to build the project, they only have the lgpl-reactor directory.

Comment: Closed code source is on a private Git repository. lgpl-reactor directory is on a public GitHub repository. I can publish a copy of  the root pom.xml as LGPL in the github repository, you are right.

Comment: Than the best thing would be to make a separate lgpgl project which will be released separately and your closed source part. Than you have no problems.

Comment: Yes i think i'll choose this solution, but it less convenient in the eclipse environment to work with both project. But maven seems not to be designed to have in the same project differents repositories for differents parts/license. (I imagine other problems with maven:release plugin for example, it can't work properly with 2 different repositories ...)

Comment: release plugin is really an argument. In Eclipse you can put those two project into eclipse and turn on workspace resolution (which is by default as far as i know).

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to apply the inverse logic, and use "mvn -f standalone-pom.xml clean package" to build lgpl-reactor as a standalone project ... But it'll be better if standalone project is build with a standard maven2 command line.