# How to resolve required bundle for Eclipse plugin

Tags: maven, eclipse-plugin, tycho, p2

I want to build some Eclipse plugins sequentially (say A , B , C , D) using Tycho and then put them in p2 repository once all plugins are built.

Now, plugin B has dependency on plugin A. In plugin B's manifest file, A is given in required bundles section.

But, as A is not present in p2 repo yet as I am building p2 repo at the end, i.e once all plugins are built. Because I want to build a single p2 repo for all plugins (count is around 50).

These all plugins are present in single folder.

How can I resolve this dependency?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom pom.xml filename in Maven multimodule for Tycho](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33396390/custom-pom-xml-filename-in-maven-multimodule-for-tycho)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could follow a similar multi-module pattern as the one described in "[Custom pom.xml filename in maven multimodule for tycho](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33396390/6309)"

```
<!-- in file pom.xml -->
<modules>
  <module>A/pom.xml</module>
  <module>B/pom.xml</module>
  <module>C/pom.xml</module>
  <module>D/pom.xml</module>
</modules>

<!-- in file pom-tycho.xml -->
<modules>
  <module>A/pom.xml</module>
  <module>B/pom.xml</module>
  <module>C/pom.xml</module>
  <module>D/pom.xml</module>
</modules>
```

The idea is that a build order in a multi-module project follows the declaration order within the `<module>` element.