# pom specific different pom file for submodules

Tags: maven-2

I have a project that will build from multiple submodules. Can I specify different pom files for different submodule? If so, how to do it?

parent project has the following modules

```
<modules>
    <module>../module-1</module>
        <!-- I want to use module1.xml for this module -->
    <module>../module-2</module>
        <!-- I want to use module2.xml for this module -->
    <module>../module-3</module>
        <!-- I want to use module3.xml for this module -->
</modules>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just specify the full path of the pom file you want to use for each sub-module.

```
<modules>
    <module>path/to/the/module1.xml</module>
    <module>path/to/the/module2.xml</module>
    <module>path/to/the/module3.xml</module>
</modules>
```

Reference: 
[Custom pom.xml filename in Maven multimodule for Tycho](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33396390/custom-pom-xml-filename-in-maven-multimodule-for-tycho)